# Cant connect my css to style path

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- This lets the browser know it is a html5 document -->
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML5 Synta and Coding Style</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css"> <!-- This is the external stylesheet that links to the page and alters the feel and look of the page -->
```

Comment: http://frazzy241.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1  all my pages work except one

Comment: That path `../` would suggest that your css file is in a folder one level _lower_ than the html page. Where is the CSS file in relation to the HTML?

Comment: http://imgur.com/NeVB64c

Comment: If the page is index.html then the path would simply be `style.css`. Remove `../`. They are in the same folder.

Comment: the code up there is for contact page, the page is contact.html

Comment: Am I supposed to guess were that page is? _Give us enough information to help!_

Comment: My pages folder - http://imgur.com/mUDcS1g

Comment: Where is the .css file in your screenshots? What page out of displayed 4 are you trying to link to .css?

Comment: its in previous folder and contact page

Answer (score 0):

1.close  and  tags.
2.select full address of your css or use [base](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_base.asp&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjG_4Pu1JTSAhUrAsAKHZokA6EQFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNFdAIBzl2zpiAZcKfVkNfPQ8lHR_Q) tag.